# Иконки программы в зависимости от ОС

Tags: иконки, delphi

Доброго времени суток!

Хотелось бы научится изменять иконку программы
в зависимости от операционной системы...
По типу как папки, скинул на флешку, а отображается 
под разными ОС по-своему...
Нет идей как это запрограммировать до запуска программы?

Comment: Вам не приходило в голову, что папки отображаются по разному не потому, что их так запрограммировал производитель флэшки, а потому что... в разных версиях ОС разные иконки папок?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Простого решения, разумеется нет, поскольку ваше приложение при открытии папки проводником должно **автоматически** предоставить ему некоторую иконку, которая будет им отрисована.

Соответственно, простой способ - до первого запуска хранить любую иконку, а после первого запуска патчить свой фрагмент `.exe`, куда и зашит ресурс иконки, заменяя ее на необходимую.

Сложный способ - вешать глобальный хук на соответствующий вызов получения иконки *(готов допустить, что его, может быть, придется перехукивать и на уровне `Native API`)* и опять же, на лету патчить ресурс, демонстрируя ту иконку, которая вам нужна. В этом способе даже в первый раз иконка будет показана правильная.

**В общем, задачка интересная, но, естественно, ни один человек в здравом уме таким заниматься не станет :)**

Comment: Да уж, в здравом уме не станет =)
Интересный момент про ресурсы... Мат. часть не читал, про них, не было возможности. Возможно можно отправить ОС за ресурсами в другой файл?
Может быть есть в PE(Portable Executable) модели такая лазейка...

Comment: >> Сложный способ - вешать глобальный хук на соответствующий вызов получения иконки
Каким образом ты повесишь глобальный хук (и вообще выполнишь какой-то код) до запуска своего приложения?
Топикстартеру следовало указать, что внешний вид файлов и папок зависит только от иконок в системных библиотеках.
Описанный ниже фокус с большой иконкой 256х256 будет работать только в том случае, когда выбран вид папок Extra large icons. В остальных случаях подставится иконка меньшего размера.

Comment: Таким же образом можно запихнуть несколько изображений в ресурсы приложения и выдавать нужный в зависимость от ОС:

     а после первого запуска патчить свой фрагмент .exe, куда и зашит ресурс иконки, заменяя ее на необходимую.

Я не прав?

Comment: >> Я не прав?

Ты не прав. Проводник не спрашивает у твоего приложения, какую иконку ему взять.

Comment: > Соответственно, простой способ - до первого запуска хранить любую иконку, а после первого запуска патчить свой фрагмент .exe, куда и зашит ресурс иконки, заменяя ее на необходимую.

Говнокод детектед. Я как последний дибил использую один exe'шник под несколькими операционными системами - под виндой и под вайном под линуксом. Дуалбут адынака. Не говоря уже о том, что иногда одна из осей запускается под виртуалбоксом с реального винчестера. Чорд.

Comment: > Сложный способ - вешать глобальный хук на соответствующий вызов получения иконки (готов допустить, что его, может быть, придется перехукивать и на уровне Native API) и опять же, на лету патчить ресурс, демонстрируя ту иконку, которая вам нужна. В этом способе даже в первый раз иконка будет показана правильная.

Говнокоде нумер 2. Стоит мелкософту выпустить патч, то все использующее Native API сломается. С другой стороны, опыт показывает, что Native API на самом деле достаточно стабилен. Но все равно использовать его весьма стремно в прикладном софте.

Comment: @gecube

- Не согласен по всем фронтам.

- `Wine` в рамках этого вопроса обсуждать мне кажется глупым. Давайте еще все приложения под `Windows` проверять под `ReactOS`.

- Как можно запустить с реального винчестера **другую** версию ОС?

- На стабильность поведения `Native API` полагаются многие `security` пакеты (и руткиты `:)` Там, как мне кажется, `damage` будет посерьезнее, чем неправильно показанная иконка.

- Вообще, если решать такую задачу в `production'e`, то логику выбора иконки нужно зашивать в инсталлятор.

- У вас, кстати, есть какие-нибудь идеи по поводу этой задачки?

Comment: @Flammable, лолшто? Читай, что выше писано! =)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать

> Wine в рамках этого вопроса обсуждать мне кажется глупым. Давайте еще все приложения под Windows проверять под ReactOS.

дело не в wine как таковом. Я еще могу вспомнить время, когда сидел в дуалбуте 98/NT4, т.к. под NT4 бОльшая часть игрушек не шла, а учился программировать я именно под NT4.

> Как можно запустить с реального винчестера другую версию ОС?

Виртуализация. Странно, что Вы про это не слышали. Запущена хостовая ось, в ней гипервизор, а под ним уже работает операционка, запущенная с отдельного раздела реального винчестера, а не с образа нжмд...

Comment: > На стабильность поведения Native API полагаются многие security пакеты (и руткиты :) Там, как мне кажется, damage будет посерьезнее, чем неправильно показанная иконка.

Вероятно, да.

> Вообще, если решать такую задачу в production'e, то логику выбора иконки нужно зашивать в инсталлятор.

Мне кажется сам вопрос некорректен. Нам ведь не нужно менять иконку exeшника. А для практических задач нужно обычно менять иконку ярлыка, который в меню пуск или на рабочем столе. А вот эта проблема уже решается существенно проще, т.к. иконку для ярлыка можно всегда задать отдельно.

Comment: @Asen
    >> лолшто? Читай, что выше писано! =)

Выше написано, что ты не прав.

Comment: А вот по поводу ярлыков - это интересный вариант решения... А для них можно указывать относительные пути расположения файлов?

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться тем, что иконку [ищет проводник](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx) в ресурсах приложения. И для висты/7 поддерживаются большие иконки большого размера 256 на 256. А ХР их ещё не поддерживает. Конечно, это грязный хак, но по другому - только патчить проводник. 
Но пользователь может зайти с TotalCommander или другой программы и приплыли...

а вот картинки папок отображаются по разному, потому что картинки для папок хранятся не на флешке, а в системных каталогах.

Answer (score 2):

Я немного не понял вопрос, нужно программно менять иконки как иконки папок?

Если офф топ,то извин.

У `Application` есть вроде свойство `Icon` - её вроде и менять надо...

Давно этим занимался просто....

Comment: Разумеется. В свойствах проекта, Application -> Icon.